# Ifelse statement returning only NA

Tags: r, if-statement

I am running this ifelse statement in R which is only producing NAs. Can you please help me with where I have gone wrong.

I am trying to identify dawn, day, dusk, night preriods of a data set. I am using the same POSIXct format for all time/date.

Below is an example of my data (Burst$starttime)

```
Event   Start.time

1   19/05/2020 16:01:21

2 19/05/2020 16:02:49

3   19/05/2020 19:18:19

4   21/05/2020 22:44:57

5   23/05/2020 19:43:59

6   23/05/2020 19:59:29

7   23/05/2020 20:39:05

8   23/05/2020 22:12:46

9   24/05/2020 0:56:22

10  24/05/2020 1:12:56
```

And the 'Sunlight' data

```
date    DawnEnd DawnStart   DuskEnd DuskStart
1   19/05/2020  19/05/2020 8:17:54  19/05/2020 6:17:54  19/05/2020 18:29:34 19/05/2020 16:29:34

2   19/05/2020  19/05/2020 8:17:54  19/05/2020 6:17:54  19/05/2020 18:29:34 19/05/2020 16:29:34

3   19/05/2020  19/05/2020 8:17:54  19/05/2020 6:17:54  19/05/2020 18:29:34 19/05/2020 16:29:34

4   21/05/2020  21/05/2020 8:19:23  21/05/2020 6:19:23  21/05/2020 18:28:21 21/05/2020 16:28:21

5   23/05/2020  23/05/2020 8:20:50  23/05/2020 6:20:50  23/05/2020 18:27:13 23/05/2020 16:27:13

6   23/05/2020  23/05/2020 8:20:50  23/05/2020 6:20:50  23/05/2020 18:27:13 23/05/2020 16:27:13

7   23/05/2020  23/05/2020 8:20:50  23/05/2020 6:20:50  23/05/2020 18:27:13 23/05/2020 16:27:13

8   23/05/2020  23/05/2020 8:20:50  23/05/2020 6:20:50  23/05/2020 18:27:13 23/05/2020 16:27:13

9   24/05/2020  24/05/2020 8:21:33  24/05/2020 6:21:33  24/05/2020 18:26:42 24/05/2020 16:26:42

10  24/05/2020  24/05/2020 8:21:33  24/05/2020 6:21:33  24/05/2020 18:26:42 24/05/2020 16:26:42

11  24/05/2020  24/05/2020 8:21:33  24/05/2020 6:21:33  24/05/2020 18:26:42 24/05/2020 16:26:42

12  24/05/2020  24/05/2020 8:21:33  24/05/2020 6:21:33  24/05/2020 18:26:42 24/05/2020 16:26:42

13  24/05/2020  24/05/2020 8:21:33  24/05/2020 6:21:33  24/05/2020 18:26:42 24/05/2020 16:26:42




Burst$Sunlight <- if_else (Burst$Start.time >Sunlight$DawnStart && Burst$Start.time <Sunlight$DawnEnd, "Dawn", 
                           if_else (Burst$Start.time > Sunlight$Dawnend && Burst$Start.time < Sunlight$DuskStart, "Day",
                                    if_else (Burst$Start.time >Sunlight$DuskStart &&Burst$Start.time < Sunlight$DuskEnd,"Dusk",
                                             if_else (Burst$Start.time <Sunlight$DuskEnd && Burst$Start.time >Sunlight$DawnStart, "Night", "NA" ))))
```

Comment: `&&` is not vectorized. Use `&`, the vectorized version. Additionally, the way your data is printing makes it seem kike it is not a proper datetime class, just a string. You should convert it. If you need more help, please share a copy/pasteable sample of data including class and structure information, as produced by `dput()`, for example `dput(Burst[1:5, ])` and `dput(Sunglight[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows of each.

Comment: Oh, and `"NA"` is the letters N and A in a string. `NA` without quotes is a missing value - though `if_else` is strict so you'll need to use `NA_character_` to specify a missing value of the `character` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you provided a sample of your dataset or similar data we could troubleshoot. However, I would strongly suggest checking out the `case_when()` function for multiple conditions. See for instance [here](https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/case-when-r/).

Comment: This looks like it could be a comment (which is a privilege after 50 reputation) rather an answer (solution) itself.